# Sequelize DataTypes TypeError: Cannot read property 'INTEGER' of undefined

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have a Sequelize `DataTypes.INTEGER` issue when defining a model. I'm following an example in ebook titled "Building APIs with Node.js". I'm a beginner trying to grasp Express and Sequelize.

Error details:

```
> /home/xxx/workspace/ntask-api/models/tasks.js:9
>       type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
>                      ^ TypeError: Cannot read property 'INTEGER' of undefined
>     at Function.module.exports (/home/xxx/workspace/ntask-api/models/tasks.js:9:21)
>     at Consign.into (/home/xxx/workspace/ntask-api/node_modules/consign/lib/consign.js:239:17)
>     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/xxx/workspace/ntask-api/index.js:13:5)
>     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
>     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
>     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
>     at startup (node.js:119:16)
>     at node.js:902:3
```

Code sample below in `/models/tasks.js`:

```
> module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes){
>     //console.log(DataTypes.INTEGER);
>     const Tasks = sequelize.define("Tasks", {     id: {
>       type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
>       primaryKey: true,
>       autoIncrement: true     },  title: {
>       type: DataTypes.STRING,
>       allowNull: false,
>       validate: {         notEmpty: true
>       }   },  done: {
>       type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
>       allowNull: false,
>       defaultValue: false     }
>     }, 
>     {     classMethods:{
>       associate: function(models){        Tasks.belongsTo(models.Users, {
>           onDelete: "CASCADE",
>           foreignKey: {           allowNull: false
>           }       }); 
>       }   }
>     });
>     return Tasks; };
```

I also tried the suggestion from [TypeError: object is not a function when defining models in NodeJs using Sequelize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17311908/typeerror-object-is-not-a-function-when-defining-models-in-nodejs-using-sequeli#answer-18924148) by adding this to the top of models/tasks.js file but same error.

```
var DataTypes = require('sequelize/lib/data-types');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sequelize changes a lot, so the answer of stackoverflow might not be correct.

If you check out the sequelize doc ([link](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/models-definition/))

They start to use `Sequelize.XXXX` instead

here is the example from the doc

```
var Project = sequelize.define('project', {
  title: Sequelize.STRING,
  description: Sequelize.TEXT
})

var Task = sequelize.define('task', {
  title: Sequelize.STRING,
  description: Sequelize.TEXT,
  deadline: Sequelize.DATE
})
```

hence, you have 2 ways to achieve that

1. `require('sequelize')` in every model file
2. `require('sequelize')` in the `index` file and pass it to every model file

Comment: Thanks @hiEven, will try it out.

Comment: It worked like a charm! ...just stuck with 1. but will try 2. later. Thanks again.